# Sum values in relation 3 layers in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, cakephp

## Huston, I have a problem;

### Problem

So, I have a EAV models in my database, Entity, Attribute, Value. The relations between are:

- Production hasMany Entity -> Entity belongsTo Production
- Entity hasMany Attribute  -> Attribute belongsTo Entity
- Attribute hasMany Value   -> Value belongsTo Attribute

The table values
---value (INT 3) , 
---label (VARCHAR 65), 
---id (INT 11 AI)

I Can save the relations in my database, but, my application needs to return the SUM of Value.value a specific production, example:

The final user, need the consolidate of as Production by month of created. So, now, my application return is this:

```
(int) 0 => array(
        'Production' => array(
            'myconditions' => 'HereIsNotAProblem'
        ),
        'Entity' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '11',
                'label' => 'Acompanhamento Familiar',
                'production_id' => '8',
                    'Attribute' => array(
                        (int) 0 => array(
                            'id' => '33',
                            'label' => 'Nascidos vivos no m?s',
                            'entity_id' => '11',
                            'Value' => array(
                                (int) 0 => array(
                                    'id' => '1',
                                    'label' => '< 2500g',
                                    'value' => '0',
                                    'attribute_id' => '33'
                                    ),              
                            )
                    )
            )
)
```

I need to return:

```
(int) 0 => array(
        'Production' => array(
            'myconditions' => 'HereIsNotAProblem'
        ),
        'Entity' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '11',
                'label' => 'Acompanhamento Familiar',
                'production_id' => '8',
                    'Attribute' => array(
                        (int) 0 => array(
                            'id' => '33',
                            'label' => 'Nascidos vivos no m?s',
                            'entity_id' => '11',
                            'Value' => array(
                                (int) 0 => array(
                                    'id' => '1',
                                    'label' => '< 2500g',
                                    'SUM' => 'TOTAL_SUM',
                                    'attribute_id' => '33'
                                    ),              
                            )
                    )
            )
)
```

How I do this?

Answer (score 0):

So when you query your data you need to left join Values to Attributes and use SUM expression. You can see similar example here, but using COUNT: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-leftjoinwith